# Making Kiddush for a group of women

Tags: minhag, kiddush, grammatical-gender

If one makes kiddush for a group of women should they say סברי גברותי before the bracha instead of סברי מרנן?

I ask because saying listen up misters when making kiddush for only women feels weird. it also feels incorrect and lying. Women are not misters. I dont believe there is an obligation to say savri meranan. I believe it is there to help the others know that you are making kiddush for them.

Comment: Probably מרתן would be a better grammatical parallel, though I'm not convinced it matters what you say. Maybe try "Y'all better listen up now!"

Comment: How about dropping the מרנן and only say סברי?

Comment: Actually, I have heard numerous people say *Robotai U'gevirotai* when there is a mixed crowd, which is frequently the case with families or when guests are there. I have been using this phrase out of habit. The phrase is a minhag (don't recall its origin) and is optional, AFAIK.

Comment: @DanF The phrase originates from the Tanhuma but today it's recognized simply as calling the listeners to attention to bare in mind the blessing (OC [Rema 174:8](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_קעד#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97)) which, IMHO, can be done by סברי alone. However the phrase isn't inhibitive.

Comment: I remember seeing somwhere(don't remember where) that the סברי has nothing to do with the people present but to remind of us of the days of the Sanhedrin,since when they gave someone skeliah they would first get them intoxicated and throw them off of a height of 2 floors,so when we use wine for kiddush many say lechaim after the hagefen to remind us that our wine drinking should be for life...

Comment: @sam that's the Tanhuma I referred to, but see the Rema I cited as well.